# how to handle time zone in .ics calendar file for karachi/pakistan

Tags: php, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ICS timezone not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626114/ics-timezone-not-working)

I'm working on my calendar app and I have created a .ics file manually and also with PHP code

I have also succeeded to sync my calender with Google, outlook and iphone.

Now the problem is this : how to handle time zone my meetings have different time in time zone.

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:UTC
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19700101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:+0500
TZNAME:PST
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Etc/GMT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19700101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:+0500
TZNAME:PST
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

I have to set the time zone components for Pakistan.

Could you tell me what I have to change ?

Comment: I tried this                                          BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:(GMT+0500) Islamabad / Karachi / Tashkent
BEGIN:STANDARD 
DTSTART:16010101T000000 
TZOFFSETFROM:+0600 
TZOFFSETTO:+0500
TZNAME:PKT 
END:STANDARD 
END:VTIMEZONE

Comment: @user1752752: You find all fields documented here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6350 and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2445

Comment: this is also not working..........                     BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Karachi
BEGIN:STANDARD 
DTSTART:16010101T000000 
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000 
TZOFFSETTO:+0500
TZNAME:PKT 
END:STANDARD 
END:VTIMEZONE.........

Comment: Don't try further. First read what needs to be done, then just do. If the first try does not work, read the specs next.